# Angular Karma - Component undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner

I'm trying to unit test a component that requires a Resolver, Router and ActivatedRoute as dependencies. I've tried to use the RouterTestingModule and mock my resolver to provide them in the testing module, but it seems to have some side effects on the creation of the component instance.

Here is the code of my component:

**History.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Transaction } from '../models/transaction.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-history',
  templateUrl: './history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./history.component.scss']
})
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  history: Transaction[] = [];
  selectedTransaction: Transaction | undefined;
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.history = this.route.snapshot.data.history;
    const routeSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.id) {
        this.setSelectedTransaction(+params.id);
      }
    });
    this.subscription.add(routeSubscription);
  }

  setSelectedTransaction(transactionId: number): void {
    const historyTransaction = this.history.find((transaction) => transaction.id === transactionId);
    this.selectedTransaction = historyTransaction;
  }

  displayTransaction(transaction: Transaction): void {
    this.router.navigate(['transactions', transaction.id]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And here is the current unit test:

**History.spec.ts**

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, Resolve, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Transaction } from '../models/transaction.model';

import { HistoryComponent } from './history.component';
import { HistoryResolver } from './history.resolver';

const mockRawTransactions = [
  {
    "id":"1",
    "created_at":"2016-01-01T08:30:39-0300",
    "counterparty_name":"Uber",
    "debit":"false",
    "credit":"true",
    "amount":"44.20",
    "currency":"EUR",
    "operation_type":"refund",
    "attachements":[  
      {  
          "url":"https:\/\/fakeimg.pl\/350x200\/?text=Hello"
      }
    ],
  }
];
const mockTransactions = mockRawTransactions.map((transaction) => new Transaction(transaction));

class HistoryMockResolver implements Resolve<Transaction[]> {

  resolve(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
    return of(mockTransactions);
  }
}

describe('HistoryComponent', () => {
  const historyRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'transactions', component: HistoryComponent },
    { path: 'transactions/:id', component: HistoryComponent },
  ];
  let component: HistoryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HistoryComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HistoryComponent ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(historyRoutes),
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              params: { id: 1 },
            },
          },
        },
        { provide: HistoryResolver, useClass: HistoryMockResolver },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HistoryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    console.log('Component', component);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should display transactions', () => {
    component.history = mockTransactions;
    expect(component.history).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.history).toHaveSize(mockRawTransactions.length);
  });

  it('should display a single transaction', () => {
    component.history = mockTransactions;
    component.displayTransaction(component.history[0]);
    expect(component.selectedTransaction).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.selectedTransaction).toEqual(component.history[0]);
  });
});
```

The component is defined and well displayed in the console.log while running the tests in Karma, but Karma raises errors for each test case and evaluates the component as undefined.

Here is the first error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
at HistoryComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/history/history.component.ts:22:45)
at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2486:1)
at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2457:1)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:2408:1)
at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9207:1)
at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:9306:1)
at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10532:1)
at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10557:1)
at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22569:1)
at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:141:1)
```

[image: Karma raised errors and console]

What should I fix in my testing module ?

Comment: Can you share the error message being printed by karma?

Comment: @deepakchethan I added the first error triggered by Karma, the followings are based on the same issue

Comment: wrong field here `snapshot: {params: { id: 1 }, },`. should be `snapshot: {data: { id: 1 },            },`. according to referencing it via `this.route.snapshot.data.history`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `this.route.snapshot.data.history` and data being undefined as your have not passed it in your mock activated snapshot.

You can update your provider for activated route snapshot in `History.spec.ts`

```
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    snapshot: {
      params: { id: 1 },
      data: {history: 'something-history-obj'}
    },
  },
},
```

Or you can always use `this.route.snapshot.data?.history` within `History.component.ts` if it is indeed nullable